# Unwanted repeating C# function call - stalled

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services

I have a C# webservice that is called from javascript using ajax. The function call in C# is repeating for no good reason around 6 times, until the call stalls. I have identified what is causing it, I just have no clue why. It occurs when a property of the returned custom object (which is another custom object) is assigned to.

I can put a breakpoint on the C# function call anywhere, and it will be hit around 6 times before the webservice response handler gets a stalled error.

The webservice call:

```
function loadPeriodData(userID, loadHandler) {
    var params = { userID: userID };
    ajaxHelper.callMethod({
        handler: loadPeriodDataHandler,
        params: {
            input: params
        },
        method: 'LoadPeriodData',
        context: {
            loadHandler: loadHandler
        }
    });
}
function loadPeriodDataHandler(response, textStatus, context) {
    if (response.isError) {
        errorHandler.logError(response.code, response.errorMessage);
    } else {
        context.loadHandler(response.results);
    }
}
```

The C# webservice function, and the functions it calls:

```
public interface IJobTime
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    LoadPeriodDataOutput LoadPeriodData(LoadPeriodDataInput input);
}

public class JobTime : IJobTime
{
    public LoadPeriodDataOutput LoadPeriodData(LoadPeriodDataInput input)
    {
        LoadPeriodDataOutput output = new LoadPeriodDataOutput();

        try
        {
            output.results = Profile.LoadPeriodData(input.userID);
            output.isError = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            output.isError = true;
            output.errorMessage = ex.Message;
        }

        return output;
    }
}

public class Profile
{
    public static LoadPeriodDataOutputObject LoadPeriodData(Guid UserID)
    {
        LoadPeriodDataOutputObject results = new LoadPeriodDataOutputObject();
        results.CurrentWeek = new ProfileSection();
        return results;
    }
}
```

The offending line, which if the 'output.results = ' part is commented, doesn't repeatedly call:

```
output.results = Profile.LoadPeriodData(input.userID);
```

The object class being created:

```
[DataContract]
public class LoadPeriodDataInput : JobTimeInput
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid userID;
}

[DataContract]
public class LoadPeriodDataOutput : JobTimeOutput
{
    [DataMember]
    public LoadPeriodDataOutputObject results;
}

[DataContract]
public class LoadPeriodDataOutputObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public ProfileSection CurrentWeek;
}

[DataContract]
public class ProfileSection
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartDate;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime EndDate;
    [DataMember]
    public float TotalHours = 0;
    [DataMember]
    public List<WorkedItem> WorkedJobs = new List<WorkedItem>();
    [DataMember]
    public List<WorkedItem> WorkedQuotes = new List<WorkedItem>();
    [DataMember]
    public string StartDateString
    {
        get
        {
            return StartDate.ToString("d MMM yyyy");
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string EndDateString
    {
        get
        {
            return EndDate.ToString("d MMM yyyy");
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class WorkedItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
    [DataMember]
    public float Hours;
    public WorkedItem(string name, float hours)
    {
        Name = name;
        Hours = hours;
    }
}
```

What I have ruled out:

- Repeated calls from javascript - Network tab in Chrome shows only one call and response

I believe it is something to do with the custom object ProfileSection, because if the LoadPeriodDataOutputObject.CurrentWeek is a string instead of ProfileSection, we have no problems.

Any clues?